# Trouble starting Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to start my Oracle database by clicking on sqldeveloper.exe and when it prompts me to enter the full path of java.exe, I select it but it doesn't do anything after that:

[image: enter full pathname for java.exe]

help!

Comment: Starting Oracle SQL Developer won't start the Oracle database.

Comment: To start SQL Developer,  Just input up to 1.8.0_231...leave off the rest of the path

Answer (score 0):

Actually, running SQL Developer won't start the database. That's done elsewhere; do you have the database installed on your computer?

As of the problem you have: I'd suggest you to download & install SQL Developer version which **includes JDK**. That solves problems people usually have with different SQL Developer & Java versions. Because, maybe your SQL Developer version doesn't run with Java you have (or vice versa), but you didn't specify the tool version.

Comment: Where do I find the actual database?

Comment: If you didn't install it, then you (most probably) don't have it. It is installed as a separate product, downloadable from the Oracle Technology Network. Or, if you're in the network, maybe you can access it that way.